# Verilog code not working

Tags: verilog, vivado

So, I am trying to build an 8 bit multiplier in verilog. I am using an add/shift method to do it that uses a register. Whenever I run the code, it produces a result that isn't right. My verilog is:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module Mul8bit(
input [7:0] Multiplier,
input [7:0] Multiplicand,
input Clock,
output [15:0] led
);
reg M;
reg [16:0] ACC = 0;
reg start=1;
reg state = 0;
reg [15:0] led;


always @(posedge Clock)
      begin
           led <= ACC[15:0];
      end

always @(posedge Clock)
    begin
                M = ACC[0];

                case (state)
                    0:
                        if(start)
                        begin
                            begin
                             state = 1;
                             ACC[7:0]<=Multiplier[7:0];
                        end

                    end
                    1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15:
                        begin
                            if(M)
                                begin
                                    ACC[16:8] <= ACC[15:8] + Multiplicand[7:0];   // Add
                                    state <= (state+1); // increase the state
                                end
                            else
                                begin
                                    ACC <= (ACC) >> 1;
                                    state <= (state+2);
                                end
                        end

                    2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16: 
                        begin
                            ACC <= (ACC) >> 1;
                            state <= (state+1); 
                        end

                    17:
                        begin
                            led <= ACC[15:0];
                            start <= ~start;
                            state <= 0;
                        end
                endcase
```

Additionally, this is my testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Company: 
// Engineer: 
// 
// Create Date: 11/16/2016 08:12:51 PM
// Design Name: 
// Module Name: 8bitMultiplier
// Project Name: 
// Target Devices: 
// Tool Versions: 
// Description: 
// 
// Dependencies: 
// 
// Revision:
// Revision 0.01 - File Created
// Additional Comments:
// 
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module Mul8bit_tb(
    );
    reg [7:0] Multiplier = 8'b10101010;
    reg [7:0] Multiplicand = 8'b00001111; 
    reg Clock = 1'b0;

    wire [15:0] led;

    Mul8bit Multi(Multiplier, Multiplicand, Clock, led);
    initial
    begin
    end
    always
    #5
    Clock = ~Clock;
endmodule
```

So, regardless of whehter the clock keeps going, the program should stop once it enters state 17. However, it continues going and the output is:
[image]

Is there any clear reason the program doesn't stop once it gets to state 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

Look at your declaration for `state` and see if it could ever hold the value 17.

Comment: What do you mean? It starts at 0 and has to enter the zero case. Depending on whether its odd or even, it enters that case and increments to the next state. So if we are at state 15 and M=1, increment state so that at the next call, we go to state 16. From there we increment by 1 again and we go to 17.

Comment: NVM. i figured it out. So sorry. My bad. Now everything makes sense.